# Cannot update package from ppa

Tags: apt, ppa, apt-cache

I cannot upgrade handbrake using `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases`

Under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I find the following file `stebbing-handbrake-releases-trusty.list`
This contains the correct links:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu trusty main
```

Output from `sudo apt-cache policy handbrake`:

```
  Geïnstalleerd: 0.9.9+dfsg-2~2.gbpa4c3e9build1
  Kandidaat:     0.9.9+dfsg-2~2.gbpa4c3e9build1
  Versietabel:
 *** 0.9.9+dfsg-2~2.gbpa4c3e9build1 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So obviously it only is searching in the official ppa's and not the John Stebbins PPA which contains an updated version.

How can I make Ubuntu updating from this PPA please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should have read the PPA description...

To install this version:

```
apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

Instead of `handbrake` (the default version in Ubuntu's repositories) so obviously it could not upgrade using

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade handbrake
```

Answer (score 2):

Handbrake can be updated to the latest stable version without adding a PPA to your software sources, by installing the Handbrake snap package.

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
sudo snap install handbrake-jz
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I wasn't aware that snap is also supported on 14.04.